# Manually order Projects in Blogdown

Tags: hugo, blogdown

I'm using Blogdown to create a website and I'm using the 'Project' section for previous work experience. Is there any way to order each post in the the 'Project' section manually? As it is they are ordered alphabetically - however I would like to order them manually (based on reverse chronological order).

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Which hugo theme would you be using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to arrange posts manually, try this: Add a `weight` in your YAML header. small weighted posts will appear first. For example, in post 1

```
---
title: I am a title
author: me
weight: 1
---
```

In post 2:

```
---
title: I am also a title
author: me
weight: 2
---
```

This works because that Hugo arranges the order of content regarding this default order: Weight > Date > LinkTitle > FilePath.

Buuut, how the ordering is implemented in each template may be different, in that case, you need to modify the template as well.

[Source from the manual](https://gohugo.io/templates/lists#order-content)

Comment: Yes, @TC-Zhang that worked! Thank you so much! I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Emi I'm using the academic theme.